# Log any WooCommerce Legacy API Request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to log any request that is made to the WooCommerce Legacy API? What is the hook for it?

I've tried: rest_pre_serve_request and woocommerce_api_request.

A log file to be created. The code I have to log the request is as follows...

```
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'tb_create_admin_menu']);
        add_action('rest_pre_serve_request', [$this, 'tb_log_api_requests'], 9999, 4);
    }

    public function tb_log_api_requests($served, $result, $request, $rest_server) {
        $log_file = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/mycustomlogness.log';
        file_put_contents($log_file, print_r($request, true) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

Comment: In case you weren't aware, the legacy API will be removed early 2024.